# regex optional group is skipped

Tags: c#, regex, option-type, regex-group

I'm trying to capture optional group inside required group. This is my regex so far:

```
BEGIN
(?<body>
     (?<A>.*?)               # in my regex just .*?
     (?<B>START.*?STOP)?
     (?<C>.*?)               # in my regex just .*?
)
END
```

and for input:

```
junk1 BEGIN junk2 START content STOP junk3 END junk4
```

I'm getting this:

```
match: 'BEGIN junk2 START content STOP junk3 END' # ok
group 'body':  ' junk2 START content STOP junk3 ' # ok
group 'A': ''                                     # expected: ' junk2 '
group 'B': not found                              # expected: 'START content STOP'
group 'C': ' junk2 START content STOP junk3 '     # expected: ' junk3 '
```

groups A and C putted just for reference purpose

Why group B is not matched even if there is correct data and I get expected result if group B is not optional?

Comment: You mean to write `STOP` instead of `END` in `(?<B>START.*?END)?`, right?

Answer (score 1):

## Why it doesn't work

You must have some basic understanding of how the regex engine and [backtracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works. In this case it goes something like this:

Group `(?<A>.*?)` will match the empty string at the first attempt (as that is what the expression means: empty string or more if required).

Then we get to group `B` right after `BEGIN`, as there is no `START` here, the whole inner group will fail, and the optional group will be skipped.

Group `C` will match the empty string. Then we try to match `END`, which doesn't match. Thus the regex engine will try to backtrack the last quantifier. In this case in group `C`. It will do this till a match is found (or try the quantifiers before it, till failing).

So we end up with group `C` expanding till `END`, and then the whole expression matches.

## Example solution

A simple solution could be made if `START`/`STOP` are not allowed inside the except for in the optional group you could use an expression like:

```
BEGIN
(?<body>
     (?<A>
          (?: (?!START|STOP) . )*?   # do not match START nor STOP
     )
     (?<B>START.*?STOP)?
     (?<C>
          (?: (?!START|STOP) . )*?   # do not match START nor STOP
     )
)
END
```

Comment: This solution is perfect, thanks. - but what if START in regex is also regex - is there a way to define START regex only once?

Comment: @CzBuCHi, no way to do that in .NET regex. But you could avoid repeating it so much if you like. For example you could use your old expression for group `A`.

Answer (score 0):

In c#, pattern matching is driven by the regular expression pattern (more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), not the input text. So, what happens is group A is not required to match anything, so decission delayed, group B is not required to match anything, so decission delayed, group C is not required to match anything but end of regular expression is reached. Group C is matched agains the input string, and gets assigned all what you expect to be in group B. And if you use a right to left pattern matching, all the content will be to group A.

Answer (score 0):

Constructs earlier in the pattern are prioritized over those later in the pattern, and the lazy quantifier (`*?`) prioritizes shorter matches. So the best match will always be to not match anything the `A` group, and since `START` can't match at the first position, it will be skipped. Finally the `C` group will eat the rest of the string, since the `END` is not optional.

Use this instead:

```
BEGIN
(?<body>
    (?<A>.*?)
    (?:
        (?<B>START.*?STOP)
        (?<C>.*?)
    )?
)
END
```

It will force the `A` group to eat as much as it can, up until the first match of `B` if it exists.